# Search the record based on struct values in golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, datastore

I am writing a service for search functionality. when i am passing values in the body to get the specific record i am able to get it based on the struct value only for PHONE.

I am very new to golang.

i need to search the values using all the fields  in the struct for  ex.phone or firstname or lastname of the patientstruct

my struct is as below

```
type PatientEntity struct {
    ID        int64 
    FirstName string 
    LastName  string 
    Phone     string 
}
```

my code is

```
func SearchPatientsHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    patient := &PatientEntity{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(patient); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    patients := []*PatientEntity{}  
    q := datastore.NewQuery(KINDPATIENT).Filter("FirstName =",patient.FirstName) 

    keys, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &patients)

    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        return
    }

    json.NewEncoder(res).Encode(patients)
}
```

i need to search with all the values of struct .how can i resolve.

Comment: This article contains everything you need for this task with example code: [Index Selection and Advanced Search](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection)

Comment: Please show the values of `patient` before `NewQuery`, `patients` after `GetAll`, the value of `KINDPATIENT`. You may also want to query the datastore to make sure your data is as expected.

Comment: I want to filter the values either with PHONE or FIRSTNAME or LASTNAME. Is it possible with DATASTORE by using FILTER.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to combine filters with `OR`. According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters), this is not possible:

> Cloud Datastore currently only natively supports combining filters
>   with the AND operator.

There's a [tracking issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/36) for this, but it's been there for ages with no action.

You can instead issue a separate query for each filter, then merge the results (query for firstname, then query for lastname, then query for phone. Finally: combine all returns results while removing duplicates).

Something along the lines of (pseudocode, but that's the logic for an OR search):

```
var results []Patients
if firstname != "" {
  results = append(results, query("firstname = ", firstname)
}
if lastname != "" {
  results = append(results, query("lastname = ", lastname)
}
etc...
removeDuplicates(results)
```

Comment: `if (patient.FirstName != "" ){
  q = datastore.NewQuery(KINDPATIENT).Filter("FirstName=",patient.FirstName)
 
 }else if(patient.LastName != ""){

  q = datastore.NewQuery(KINDPATIENT).Filter("LastName =", patient.LastName)
  
 }else if(patient.Phone != ""){
  q = datastore.NewQuery(KINDPATIENT).Filter("Phone =", patient.Phone)
  
 }` 
In these way i am doing .is it makes sense

Comment: You're not doing an OR search. If I specify both `firstname` and `lastname`, you will not search for `lastname` at all. I've updated my answer with pseucode for what you want to do.

Comment: The above code is not working for me i am getting an error showing that CANNOT USE QUERY , removeDuplicates(undefined)
i am using datastore.NewQuery

Comment: I did say it was pseudocode, not actual code. you'll have to write `removeDuplicates` yourself, and `query(...)` stands for building/sending a query and parsing the result.

Comment: i stuck with that .can you help me